# iCloud Status of Apple Music After iTunes Match Scan

Tags: itunes

I just purchased and ran iTunes Match on my collection. Approximately 80% came back as Matched, 10% as Uploaded, and an additional 10% came back as Apple Music.  All my files were previously ripped or purchased MP3s.  I completely understand and expected the Matched and Uploaded results, but have no idea why the others are coming back as Apple Music. I am subscribed to Apple Music, but only have iCloud sync enabled on my PC running iTunes 12.2.2.25 (which appears to be the latest version).  Any idea 1) why these are showing up as Apple Music, and 2) how to I get them to switch to Matched as I believe they should be?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If a song in your library is recognized and is on apple music, iTunes will automatically switch the status to apple music. Currently, there is no way to switch them.